# How to echo vuejs data inside php function with laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I want to echo vuejs data inside a php function like so:

```
{{ auth()->user()->timesAddedBeer(@{{ beer.id }}) }}
```

But laravel gives me the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '{'

Can anybody tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: You could use plain `<?php` tags instead of `{{`.

Comment: That does not work since the outer braces are from the blade templating of laravel and the inner @{{ }} braces are from vuejs itself so they are not php and are needed.

Comment: Maybe triple `{{{ $data }}}` to echo?

Comment: So what's stoping you from doing something like this? `<?php auth->user->()->timesAddedBeer(?> @{{ beer.id}} <?php ) ?>`

Comment: The vuejs data is loading a fraction slower than the page so the php function is trying to execute with the laravel values of the mustache binding instead of the translated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible because the server can't access the JS value at the time executing the php script.

Comment: Then what is a solution ?

Comment: EIther pass the data to the client through PHP or use AJAX from the client